# What is the field of view(FOV) of the color camera in Kinect for Windows V2?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

Can't find it anywhere. The kinectforwindows site has the FOV for depth camera. I can't find it in the box either.

Answer (score 3):

@user1809923 is correct. I contacted the developer of the link:

http://smeenk.com/kinect-field-of-view-comparison/

And he responded with this information:

> If I remember correctly these FOV values are part of the
>   framedescriptions that you can retrieve with help of the Kinect SDK.
>   Since other people asked for the same info I will update the my blog.

I confirmed his findings by calling the frame's framedescription in the Kinect SDK code and printing the values to the screen.

Comment: he added "Data Sources" footnote to that article

Answer (score 1):

According to this post

http://smeenk.com/kinect-field-of-view-comparison/

the FOV of the color camera is 84.1 x 53.8. I am not sure, where the author found this information though.

Comment: Yeah. I couldn't find any official value. Thanks anyways

Comment: see his footnote "Data Sources": Data sources "Mentioned values were retrieved from a Kinect V1 sensor with help of the Kinect V1 SDK. The KinectSensor object contains a ColorImageStream and DepthImageStream that both contain a FrameWidth and FrameHeight in pixels and the NominalHorizontalFieldOfView and NominalVerticalFieldOfView in degrees. The DepthImageStream also contains values for the MinDepth and MaxDepth in millimeters." Also has a note for the v2 version after that

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add some more information to this, because the official Kinect Fusion documentation is really bad and because the answer here is correct but the numbers are rounded:

1. assuming, you already have a initialized  `IColorFrameSource*` (e.g. with the name `pColorFrameSource`) you should retrieve the information after you opened the reader: `pColorFrameSource->OpenReader(&m_pColorFrameReader);` with `m_pColorFrameReader` beeing `IColorFrameReader*`
2. the code to retrieve the FOV then looks like this:

   ```
   IFrameDescription *f=nullptr;   
   float fovDiago = 0;
   float fovHori = 0;
   float fovVerti = 0;
   HRESULT hh=pColorFrameSource
   ->CreateFrameDescription(ColorImageFormat::ColorImageFormat_Rgba,&f);
   if (hh == S_OK) {
       f->get_DiagonalFieldOfView(&fovDiago);
       f->get_HorizontalFieldOfView(&fovHoront);
       f->get_VerticalFieldOfView(&fovVerti);
   }
   ```

The FOV values not rounded are:

```
fovDiago =91.9000015
fovHori  =84.0999985
fovVerti =53.7999992
```